# Как запустить другое приложение из программы?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, nfc

Хочу написать программу которая работает с NFC метками (проездными метро). И сразу вопрос: может ли программа запустить приложение, которое есть на устройстве? Приведу пример:

1. Захожу домой, прикладываю телефон к метке: "включается wifi, выключается мобильный интернет".
2. Сажусь в машину, прикладываю телефон к метке: "выключается wifi, включается мобильный интернет, включается музыка и навигатор".
3. Можно ли сделать программу которая работала бы в фоне и срабатывала только приложит карту к телефону?

Т.к. я ноль с палочкой в программировании, хочу увидеть ответ понятный мне. Возможно ли написании такой программы? Есть ли уже аналоги под Windows Phone? (Для Android нашел)

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: > _Если уже есть аналоги (не только под win mobile)_ - под дрона полно, искать по 'nfc tag launcher' в маркете. [Например эта.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.widgapp.NFC_ReTAG_FREE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запустить другое приложение из программы не получится. 
1) Включить/отключить wifi и моб. интернет из приложения тоже не получится. Вы можете только открыть настройки, чтобы человек смог самостоятельно это сделать.
2) В фоне я думаю заставить работать программу с NFC тоже не получится. Вот ссылка с доступным кодом по NFC (https://nfcsmartcardreader.codeplex.com/), но там есть ряд ограничений - как по маркам телефона, так и по платформам.